# How to get the multiple lambda value in box-cox transformation?

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

I am trying to get the lambda value using the below mentioned code but while doing the inverse transformation, we get the transformed value too high due to the negative value of lambda. How can I get the positive lambda value or multiple ?
`python from scipy.stats import boxcox from scipy.special import inv_boxcox     y =[90,20,30,40,50] y,fitted_lambda= boxcox(y,lmbda=None) fitted_lambda` 
output: `-0.24598892144685428`

Here, I want the lambda value to be positive or if I have list of lambda value to select the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with, the statement "*I want the lambda value to be positive*" makes no sense at all; Box-Cox transformation is a well-defined mathematical operation, and what it will return does not in any way depend on what we may want or prefer.

Second, according to the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.boxcox.html):

> If *lmbda* is None, find the lambda that maximizes the log-likelihood function and return it as the second output argument.

so, not any *list* of returned values either - only a **single** (optimal) value is returned.

Third, Box-Cox is not a panacea; it may very well be the case that the resulting transformation of the data is not appropriate for your case (as you imply here).

Now, it's true that according again to the [SciPy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.boxcox.html):

> The Box-Cox transform is given by:
>
> ```
> y = (x**lmbda - 1) / lmbda,  for lmbda > 0
>     log(x),                  for lmbda = 0
> ```

it seems that `lmbda` is never expected to be negative; that's a puzzle, but it is most probably simply a **mistake** in the specific SciPy documentation page, and it was meant to be `lmbda != 0` instead of `lmbda > 0` [**UPDATE**: indeed it is, see comments below].

Corroboration for this:

- The [original paper](https://www.ime.usp.br/%7Eabe/lista/pdfQWaCMboK68.pdf), where in eq. (1) (p. 214) it is indeed mentioned simply `λ != 0`
- The Cross Validated threads [SciPy's stats boxcox transformation unexpected behavior: negative exponent (lambda)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/196631/scipys-stats-boxcox-transformation-unexpected-behavior-negative-exponent-lamb) (specifically on this issue) and [interpretation of boxcox with lambda equal 0](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/244550/interpretation-of-boxcox-with-lambda-equal-0)
- [This discussion](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/6873) in the SciPy Github repo, where negative values of `lmbda` routinely pop up without any contributor raising an eye
- The [documentation page](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.boxcox.html) of the similar SciPy module `scipy.special.boxcox`, where it is (correctly) mentioned `lmbda != 0`, and **not** `lmbda > 0`

Finally, it's straightforward to reproduce your experiment in R, for cross-checking your returned result:

```
library(forecast)
data = c(90,20,30,40,50) # your data
lmbda = BoxCox.lambda(data,method="loglik")
lmbda
# result:
[1] -0.25
```

which, in the limits of the numeric accuracy used, is practically identical with your reported value for `fitted_lambda` of `-0.24598892144685428` (it is a [known fact](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/6873#issuecomment-271253558) that here the numeric accuracy of the `forecast` R package is lower than SciPy's).

All in all, there does not seem to be any real issue here (coding issue or otherwise) to be resolved, it's just that the Box-Cox transformation may not be appropriate / convenient for your case.

Comment: You are correct: the line `lmbda > 0` is a mistake in the `boxcox` docstring.  That should be fixed soon.

Comment: Pull request with the one character fix: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/12650

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser cool - you saved me the time to open an issue :)